# Magento force www throws to the homepage

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

if I go to a product with www. it works and without it throws me to the homepage.
not sure how to still enforce www. but direct back to the product page and not to the homepage.
e.g:
works:
www.amazonia.com.au/powder.html

goes to homepage:
amazonia.com.au/powder.html

help much appreciated, thank you.
aaron.

Comment: What base URL have you set up in Magento admin?

Answer (score 1):

```
#This will allow both www and non www URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

plz change:

1. Sistem -> General -> Web -> "insecure" AND "secure" -> URL Base
2. change: http://amazonia.com.au/   -> To: http://www.amazonia.com.au/

Magento redirect automatic. dont need any .htaccess rule.